# unzip data in Python to XlsWriter columns

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

I have this piece of code

```
volts, voltsPhase, current, currentPhase  = zip(*Data)
```

How do i unzip the volts, voltsPhase, current, currentPhase to different columns in Xlswriter?

Thank you